# How to copy the number if contains certain number (first 4 digit) to another column - EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to search on the specific column(E), and if matched with the first 4 digit, I would like to copy the number to a different column.

- Column E is where i would like to paste all the random number(dynamic)
- Column A/B/C is static where i would add 4 digits from time to time.
- Column I/J/K is where is would like to paste the result.

[image]

PS:
I'm doing it manually and would really appreciate if someone can help me out with the automation hence no code is provided. :(

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: @JvdV, not sure if this is what you need but its says, Version 2002

Comment: No, but if you had Excel O365 you could use "FILTER" function.

Comment: oh yeah i'm using Excel 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having ExcelO365 means you may use `FILTER()`. Therefor try the below:

[image]

Formula in `I2`:

```
=FILTER($E:$E,ISNUMBER(MATCH(--LEFT($E:$E,4),A:A,0)))
```

Drag right to `K2`. Now, this is dynamic and will change accordingly upon data entry in column `E:E`, or changing values in `A:C`.

Comment: As you can see, I didn't. @gafm

Answer (score 0):

this is the code to execute on sheet 1, it goes through the entire column E and validates through the formula of counting if in each of the first three columns and assigns the value found in the corresponding columns.

```
Sub macro()
Dim Static_Data As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1")
Active_row = 2
Do While Sht.Range("E" & Active_row).Value <> ""
    Static_Data = Sht.Range("E" & Active_row).Value
    For i = 1 To 3
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sht.Columns(i), Mid(Static_Data, 1, 4)) > 0 Then
            Sht.Cells(Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i + 8).Value = Static_Data
        End If
    Next i
Active_row = Active_row + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: and what is the name of your sheet where are the data?

Comment: Sheet1, i never renamed it.

Comment: ok, sorry is that the code is in Spanish "Hoja1", it is my language you have to change it between quotes to Sheet1, that must be the error.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel versions that don't support FILTER or as an alternative you can use standard formulas for this.

If you use columns F-H as helper columns (and these columns can be hidden) then the formula in F2 will be:

> =IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(LEFT($E2,4)),A$2:A$100,1,FALSE)))=TRUE,$E2,"")

The formula can then be copied across and down. This will find your matches.

In order to then remove the blanks from the data you can use the following formula in I2 and again copy across and down. Depending on how many numbers you want to add in, you may want to extend the range A$2:A$100 in the top formula and F$2:F$100 in the bottom formula

> =IFERROR(INDEX(F$2:F$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(F$2:F$100)-ROW(F$2)+1)/(F$2:F$100<>""),ROWS(I$2:I2))),"")